# Dompdf does not show correct data every time in Laravel

Tags: laravel

When generating PDF, it works without any problems the first time. When some data changes in the DB and I want to generate PDF again, it continues to show the old data. When I want to regenerate after 2-3 hours, it works correctly again.

Have you ever encountered such a problem and solved it?

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->setPaper('A4');

$paymentHistory = PaymentHistory::where("complex_id", $complex->id)
    ->whereYear('payment_month', now()->year)
    ->whereMonth('payment_month', now()->month)
    ->get();

$apartments = Apartment::where("complex_id", $complex->id)->get();

$utilityPrice = UtilityPrice::where('complex_id', $complex->id)
    ->orderBy('start_date', 'desc')
    ->first();

$upricekv = $utilityPrice ? $utilityPrice->amount : 0;

$html = view('payment_history', [
    'paymentHistory' => $paymentHistory,
    'apartments' => $apartments,
    'upricekv' => $upricekv,
])->render();

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();

$pdfContent = $dompdf->output();

$pdfFilePath = public_path('pdf/' . $complex->name . '-payment_monthly.pdf');
file_put_contents($pdfFilePath, $pdfContent);
```

I tried clearing caches.

Comment: I think you have a problem with caching the request at the server level. Could you send headers when generating the file, from the browser?